# Optimizing Script Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, jquery-mobile, mustache

I am using script templates for creating resuable html markup in javascript. The templates are using mustache to replace tags with the correct values. The html is then rendered and rendered again by JQUery Mobile. A snippet looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                    <title>jQuery Mobile</title>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
                    <meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />



                </head>
                <body>
                    <!-- Page Templates -->

<script id="page_header_tpl" type="text/template">
<div data-role="header" class="toolbar {{#class}}{{{class}}}{{/class}}" {{#id}}id="{{{id}}}" {{/id}}>
<h1>{{{title}}}</h1>
<div data-role="ui-bar" class="ui-bar" id="ui-top">
{{#buttons}}
        {{{.}}}
{{/buttons}}
</div><!-- /navbar -->

{{#navbar}}
    {{{navbar}}}
{{/navbar}}
</div>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Function for creating the header
function createPageHeader(data) {
      html = $('#page_header_tpl').html();
    return Mustache.render(html, data);
}
 //Calling the function
 var header = createPageHeader({ class : 'aheader', id : 'my id',  title : 'Page 1'});
<script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is what sort of techniques can I use to optimze the calling and placing of template elements into html files? Fast retrieval of elements? Faster parsing by Mustache? Memory techniques? etc

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) on the client. It's fully compatible with Mustache and provides a way to [compile your templates ahead of time](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html) for even better performance.

It also adds a bunch of extra helpers but you don't have to use these if you'd like to keep your templates strictly Mustache compatible (for use on the server side for example).

Not only that it also [provides a stripped version (Handlebars runtime) of the library](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/downloads) for use with compiled templates.

A comparison article with a few more useful links can be found here - http://nimbupani.com/mustache.html